# How to launch chrome browser in background programmatically from my android app?

Tags: android

My android application need to open google chrome browser in background without ui and download some file.
Alternatively it could be great to launch google chrome ui from my android app and get back to my android app.

This is the code i wrote for that but don't get it work.

```
        Intent i = null;

        try {
            i = new Intent();
            i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString
                    ("com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // Chrome is not installed
            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        } finally {
            if(i != null) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
```

Please how can i handle this in android ?

Comment: Why don't you use a WebView that is integrated into your app? That would make a lot things easier that usingan external web browser.